# Nomenclature - Lanthanoids vs Lanthanides (and Actinides vs Actinoids)

Tags: nomenclature, rare-earth-elements

Apologies if this seems like a silly question.

Rare earth elements (the 4d series) are called by the names Lanthanides or Lanthanoids interchangeably. The same applies for the 5d series, which are called Actinides or Actinoids.

**Which one of these two terms is more preferred?** Is there an IUPAC directive preferring one over the other in scientific documents? If one is to write a paper or book regarding these elements, which term would one use? Or can both of them be used interchangeably?

Comment: Briefly, since "-ide" implies an anion, using suffix "-oid" is more preferable. I bet I saw this question before either on Chemistry.SE or on English.SE.

Comment: @andselisk I did search for a similar question on Chemistry SE but couldn't find it. Hence I posted the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [p 52, *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (‘Red Book’)*](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Red_Book_2005.pdf):

> The ending ‘ide’
>   normally indicates a negative ion, and therefore lanthanoid and actinoid are preferred to
>   lanthanide and actinide.

In practice this is almost never followed, and consequently both terms are (for all intents and purposes) interchangeable, unless the context demands a differentiation.

Comment: Let me just add that lanthanide/lanthanoid anions do not exist (at least under any reasonable conditions) so there is no concern of confusion.